# Can different SharePoint pages have seperate master pages?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

**Problem:**

I'm trying to assign a different master page for my home page apart from the rest of my site, so I was wondering if this is possible. If so, how do you implement it and what is the process for setting a different master page for a single page

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? On premises, online ? Is it a Publishing Site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the page whose master page you wish to alter. Find the <%@ Page %> directive:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="_catalogs/masterpage/<<custom2.master>>"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Update its virtual URL in above tag under the MasterPageFile attribute

Answer (score 0):

If it is sharepoint 2013 or Online just change the master page on site configuration for the root site, and on your subsites do the same with the second master page.